# How to add uuid in data.json file in Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, uuid

I have a data set in `data.json` file. I need to add `'uuid'` field to each record. The project is in Node.js.

I can read the file by using

```
module.exports.api = function(server, fs) {

  // Sample Rest Call
  server.get('/api/getData', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.json', function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send(200, JSON.parse(data));
    });

  });
};
```

I have the option to use mongoose as well.

Comment: Is there an endpoint that accepts a JSON file and saves it to the server?

Comment: Well. I need to modify my JSON file. Need to insert 'uuid' field in it. No need to save it.

Comment: @chharvey, I didnt get what did you edited and why did you down voted my question? It would be great if i get any feedback on that.

Comment: @shumanachowdhury I did not downvote your question, I only edited it. You can see revisions here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48493019/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means 100% efficient, there are of course better solutions. But you could manipulate the data returned from the JSON by looping through it and setting the index as the UUID of the current object being looped through. Like this

```
module.exports.api = function(server, fs) {

// Sample Rest Call

server.get('/api/getData', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.json', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let results = JSON.parse(data);
        let resultsWithUUID = [];
        result.forEach((res, index) => {
           res.uuid = index;
           resultsWithUUID.concat([res]);
        }
        res.send(200, resultsWithUUID);

    });
});
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I guess it can help me out. I already have uuid generated. So i can just add it to json file as you mentioned.